# React code is not running when using Webpack, React, Babel combination

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, frontend, babeljs

I've been following Petr Tichy (@ihatetomatoes) Webpack 2 tutorial series, and have got to the [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhA5LNA3MxE&index=6&list=PLkEZWD8wbltnRp6nRR8kv97RbpcUdNawY) vid which covers installing React and Babel.

I've gone over the code with a fine tooth comb and spent a couple of hours googling but I just cannot get my code to perform in the expected way.  The React method in my app.js file does not execute.

It *should* render "Hello World" into the root element of the index page, but I get nothing.

This is what I have...

./src/app.js

```
const css = require("./styles.scss");

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

./src/index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
  <body>
      <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

webpack.config.js

```
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { 
                test: /\.scss$/, 
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract( { 
                    fallback: 'style-loader', 
                    use: ['css-loader','sass-loader'] 
                } ) 
            },
            { 
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'babel-loader'
            } 
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
            title: "IWTE",
            template: './src/index.html',
            minify: {
                collapseWhitespace: true,
            },
            hash: true
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css")
    ],
    devServer: {
        contentBase: "./dist",
        compress: true,
        hot: true,
        open: true
    },
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015","react"]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "creator",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --progress --colors",
    "prod": "webpack -p"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "eslint": "^4.7.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.8.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1"
  }
}
```

Any advice or suggestions on what route to follow to debug this is greatly appreciated!  I'm a relative noob to frontend dev. Thanks!

Comment: try looking at dev tools. if your assets are being used. should find ```<script src="dist/app.js"></script>```

Comment: @ReiDien I can see that my js bundle is being created and loaded by the page.  Console log appear as expected if I add them to the script.  It's just the react code that doesn't execute, from what I can see.

Comment: and no errors on console?

Comment: could you share a repo? ill be glad to help

Comment: @ReiDien Thanks!  https://github.com/philboltt/webpackReactTest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of your package.json make a change as :

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --hot --progress --colors",
    "prod": "webpack -p"
}
```

You need to add **--hot** inside of your dev commmand to enable hot reloading.

Let me know if it doesn't work. Cheers!

Comment: Wow. I did not expect that to be the reason... but it works!  Thanks @ShubhamJain.

Comment: Glad I could help :)